# myCanvas.addKeyListener(this) throws an error in JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, events, keylistener, jogl

I want to rotate the cube if I press the left and right arrow keys to move the horizontal and vertical axis respectively. Hence I have used the keyListener interface in this program. While instantiation of the keyListener it throws an error and hereby I have attached my code for your reference.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.nio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL4.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.*;
import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyListener;

import org.joml.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Code extends JFrame implements GLEventListener,KeyListener
{   private GLCanvas myCanvas;
    
    private int renderingProgram;
    private int vao[] = new int[1];
    private int vbo[] = new int[3];
    private float cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ;
    private float objLocX, objLocY, objLocZ;
    
    // allocate variables for display() function
    private FloatBuffer vals = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(16);
    private Matrix4f pMat = new Matrix4f();  // perspective matrix
    private Matrix4f vMat = new Matrix4f();  // view matrix
    private Matrix4f mMat = new Matrix4f();  // model matrix
    private Matrix4f mvMat = new Matrix4f(); // model-view matrix
    private int mvLoc, pLoc;
    private float aspect;
    
    private int shuttleTexture;
    private int rotateX = 0,rotateY = 0;
    
    private int numObjVertices;
    private ImportedModel myModel;
    

    public Code()
    {   setTitle("Chapter6 - program3");
        setSize(600, 600);
        myCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        myCanvas.addKeyListener(this); //this line throws an error.
        myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        
        this.add(myCanvas);
        myCanvas.setFocusable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glUseProgram(renderingProgram);

        int mvLoc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "mv_matrix");
        int pLoc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "p_matrix");

        vMat.identity().setTranslation(-cameraX,-cameraY,-cameraZ);

        mMat.identity();
        mMat.translate(objLocX, objLocY, objLocZ);

        mMat.rotateX((float)Math.toRadians(20.0f));
        mMat.rotateY((float)Math.toRadians(130.0f));
        mMat.rotateZ((float)Math.toRadians(5.0f));

        mvMat.identity();
        mvMat.mul(vMat);
        mvMat.mul(mMat);

        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, false, mvMat.get(vals));
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(pLoc, 1, false, pMat.get(vals));

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shuttleTexture);

        gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, myModel.getNumVertices());
    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
    
        myModel = new ImportedModel("cube1.obj");
        renderingProgram = Utils.createShaderProgram("src/code/vertShader.glsl", "src/code/fragShader.glsl");

        float aspect = (float) myCanvas.getWidth() / (float) myCanvas.getHeight();
        pMat.identity().setPerspective((float) Math.toRadians(60.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

        setupVertices();
        cameraX = 0.0f; cameraY = 0.0f; cameraZ = 3.0f;
        objLocX = 0.0f; objLocY = 0.0f; objLocZ = 0.0f;

        shuttleTexture = Utils.loadTexture("Material5.jpg");
    }

    private void setupVertices()
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
    
        numObjVertices = myModel.getNumVertices();
        Vector3f[] vertices = myModel.getVertices();
        Vector2f[] texCoords = myModel.getTexCoords();
        Vector3f[] normals = myModel.getNormals();
        
        float[] pvalues = new float[numObjVertices*3];
        float[] tvalues = new float[numObjVertices*2];
        float[] nvalues = new float[numObjVertices*3];
        
        for (int i=0; i<numObjVertices; i++)
        {   pvalues[i*3]   = (float) (vertices[i]).x() + rotateX;
            pvalues[i*3+1] = (float) (vertices[i]).y() + rotateY;
            pvalues[i*3+2] = (float) (vertices[i]).z();
            tvalues[i*2]   = (float) (texCoords[i]).x();
            tvalues[i*2+1] = (float) (texCoords[i]).y();
            nvalues[i*3]   = (float) (normals[i]).x();
            nvalues[i*3+1] = (float) (normals[i]).y();
            nvalues[i*3+2] = (float) (normals[i]).z();
        }
        
        gl.glGenVertexArrays(vao.length, vao, 0);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
        gl.glGenBuffers(vbo.length, vbo, 0);
        
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        FloatBuffer vertBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(pvalues);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf.limit()*4, vertBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
        FloatBuffer texBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(tvalues);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuf.limit()*4, texBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[2]);
        FloatBuffer norBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(nvalues);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, norBuf.limit()*4,norBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }
    
    

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new Code();}


    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {   float aspect = (float) myCanvas.getWidth() / (float) myCanvas.getHeight();
        pMat.identity().setPerspective((float) Math.toRadians(60.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    }

    public void keyPressed(com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int key = arg0.getKeyCode();
        System.out.println(arg0.getKeyCode());
        if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT )
        {
            rotateX +=2;
            System.out.println("Left arrow is pressed");
        }
        else if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT )
            rotateY += 2;
        else if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            rotateX += 2;
        else if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_UP )
            rotateX -= 2;
        else if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_HOME )
            rotateX = rotateY = 0;
        
    }

    public void keyReleased(com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyEvent arg0) {}
}
```

**Output**:

```
The method addKeyListener(KeyListener) in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments (Code)
```

Why am I unable to add the add keylistener in opengl java?

Comment: it's because this is not a KeyListener

Comment: then what it is? @user253751

Comment: you see `import com.jogamp.newt.event.KeyListener` that means when you just write `KeyListener` it's talking about the JOGAMP one. But you need the AWT one because AWT uses AWT KeyListeners

Comment: @user253751 Yes, this is almost correct. JogAmp supports AWT, Swing, OpenJFX and its own windowing system called NEWT. Either use JOGL AWT GLCanvas with the AWT KeyListener or use GLWindow (NEWT) with NEWT KeyListener.

Comment: @DRV This example uses NEWT: https://gist.github.com/xranby/ccbcfcaef341f5bd1ba8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified and added this lines

GLProfile g = GLProfile.getMaxProgrammableCore(true);

GLCapabilities c = new GLCapabilities(g);

myCanvas = new GLCanvas(c);

Now I can able to do the Key listener interface in my program.

**Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.nio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL4.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.*;
import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import org.joml.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLContext;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class Code extends JFrame implements GLEventListener,KeyListener
{   private GLCanvas myCanvas;
    private int renderingProgram;
   private double startTime = 0.0;
    private double elapsedTime;
    private int vao[] = new int[1];
    private int vbo[] = new int[3];
    private float cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ;
    private float objLocX, objLocY, objLocZ;
    
    // allocate variables for display() function
    private FloatBuffer vals = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(16);
    private Matrix4f pMat = new Matrix4f();  // perspective matrix
    private Matrix4f vMat = new Matrix4f();  // view matrix
    private Matrix4f mMat = new Matrix4f();  // model matrix
    private Matrix4f mvMat = new Matrix4f(); // model-view matrix
    private int mvLoc, pLoc;
    private float aspect;
    
    private int shuttleTexture;
    
    private int numObjVertices;
    private ImportedModel myModel;
   
   private double tf;
   int i = 0;
   double incX;
   double incY;
   int setx = 2;
   
   boolean toggle = false;
   boolean texToggle = false;

    public Code()
    {   setTitle("Chapter6 - program3");
        setSize(600, 600);
      GLProfile g = GLProfile.getMaxProgrammableCore(true);

      GLCapabilities c = new GLCapabilities(g);
      
      myCanvas = new GLCanvas(c);

        myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
      myCanvas.addKeyListener(this);
      myCanvas.setFocusable(true);
        this.add(myCanvas);
        this.setVisible(true);
      Animator animator = new Animator(myCanvas);
        animator.start();
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
      elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
      
        tf = elapsedTime/1000.0; 
      
      if(texToggle){
           shuttleTexture = Utils.loadTexture("Material5.jpg");
      }
         else{
           shuttleTexture = Utils.loadTexture("dhoni.jpg");   
      }

        gl.glUseProgram(renderingProgram);

        int mvLoc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "mv_matrix");
        int pLoc = gl.glGetUniformLocation(renderingProgram, "p_matrix");

        vMat.identity().setTranslation(-cameraX,-cameraY,-cameraZ);
      
      for(int yUp = -1; yUp<=1; yUp += 1){
         for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
         
   
               mMat.identity();
               mMat.rotateX((float)Math.toRadians(incX));
               mMat.rotateY((float)Math.toRadians(incY));
               
               if(i==0){
               
                  mMat.translate(0*setx,yUp*setx,0*setx);
               }
               else if(i == 1){
                  mMat.translate(-1*setx,yUp*setx,0*setx);
               }
               
                else if(i == 2){
                  mMat.translate(1*setx,yUp*setx,0*setx);
               }
   
                else if(i == 3){
                  mMat.translate(0*setx,yUp*setx,-1*setx);
               }
                else if(i == 4){
                  mMat.translate(0*setx,yUp*setx,1*setx);
               }
                else if(i == 5){
                  mMat.translate(1*setx,yUp*setx,-1*setx);
               }
               else if(i == 6){
                  mMat.translate(1*setx,yUp*setx,1*setx);
               }
               
               else if(i == 7){
                  mMat.translate(-1*setx,yUp*setx,-1*setx);
               }
                else if(i == 8){
                  mMat.translate(-1*setx,yUp*setx,1*setx);
               }
   


            mMat.rotateX((float)Math.toRadians(180.f));
            mMat.rotateY((float)Math.toRadians(180.f));
            mMat.rotateZ((float)Math.toRadians(90.0f));

      
            mvMat.identity();
            mvMat.mul(vMat);
            mvMat.mul(mMat);
    
            gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvLoc, 1, false, mvMat.get(vals));
            gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(pLoc, 1, false, pMat.get(vals));
      
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
            gl.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
      
            gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
            gl.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
      
            gl.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shuttleTexture);
            
            if (toggle){
               gl.glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );
            }
            else{
               gl.glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );
            } 
            
            gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, myModel.getNumVertices());
               
      }
    }
   
   
   }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        myModel = new ImportedModel("cube1.obj");
        renderingProgram = Utils.createShaderProgram("code/vertShader.glsl", "code/fragShader.glsl");

        float aspect = (float) myCanvas.getWidth() / (float) myCanvas.getHeight();
        pMat.identity().setPerspective((float) Math.toRadians(60.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);

        setupVertices();
      cameraX = 0.0f; cameraY = 0.0f; cameraZ = 25.0f;
        objLocX = 100.0f; objLocY = 100.0f; objLocZ = 100.0f;

      if(texToggle){
           shuttleTexture = Utils.loadTexture("Material5.jpg");
      }
      else{
           shuttleTexture = Utils.loadTexture("dhoni.jpg");

      }

      
    }

    private void setupVertices()
    {   GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
    
        numObjVertices = myModel.getNumVertices();
        Vector3f[] vertices = myModel.getVertices();
        Vector2f[] texCoords = myModel.getTexCoords();
        Vector3f[] normals = myModel.getNormals();
        
        float[] pvalues = new float[numObjVertices*3];
        float[] tvalues = new float[numObjVertices*2];
        float[] nvalues = new float[numObjVertices*3];
        
        for (int i=0; i<numObjVertices; i++)
        {   pvalues[i*3]   = (float) (vertices[i]).x();
            pvalues[i*3+1] = (float) (vertices[i]).y();
            pvalues[i*3+2] = (float) (vertices[i]).z();
            tvalues[i*2]   = (float) (texCoords[i]).x();
            tvalues[i*2+1] = (float) (texCoords[i]).y();
            nvalues[i*3]   = (float) (normals[i]).x();
            nvalues[i*3+1] = (float) (normals[i]).y();
            nvalues[i*3+2] = (float) (normals[i]).z();
        }
        
        gl.glGenVertexArrays(vao.length, vao, 0);
        gl.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
        gl.glGenBuffers(vbo.length, vbo, 0);
        
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0]);
        FloatBuffer vertBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(pvalues);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf.limit()*4, vertBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1]);
        FloatBuffer texBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(tvalues);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuf.limit()*4, texBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[2]);
        FloatBuffer norBuf = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(nvalues);
        gl.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, norBuf.limit()*4,norBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyPressed");
        if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            incY  += 20.0f;
               
        else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            incY  -= 20.0f;
        else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            incX  += 20.0f;
            
        else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            incX  -= 20.0f;
        else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_E)
            setx  += 3;
        else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_C)
            setx  -= 1;
        else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_L)
            toggle = !toggle;
        else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_X)
            cameraZ -= 2.0f;
        else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_Z)
            cameraZ += 4.0f;
        else if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_T ){
           texToggle = !texToggle;

        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    
      
    
       System.out.println("keyReleased");
      
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("keyTyped");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { new Code(); }
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {   float aspect = (float) myCanvas.getWidth() / (float) myCanvas.getHeight();
        pMat.identity().setPerspective((float) Math.toRadians(60.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    }
}
```